# How to preserve format of content while writing to another file?

Tags: ruby, regex, file

I'm reading some content from a file and use a regex and `scan` to discard a few things in the file and write the content to another file.

If I look at the newly written file, it has escape characters and `"\n"` in the file instead of actual new line.

filea.txt is:

```
test
in run
]
}
end
```

I'm getting the content between 'test' and 'end' using:

```
file = File.open('filea.txt', 'r')
result = file.read    
regex = /(?<=test) .*?(?=end)/mx
ans = result.scan(regex)
```

Writing `ans` to a new file like fileb.txt puts:

```
in run'\"\n            ]\n          }
```

But, if I try writing the entire `result`, then it has correct content format in `fileb.txt`.

Comment: how do you write it? (show both cases)

Comment: Do you want to preserve format when writing the output?

Comment: @Aegis yes exactly. i need to preserve the format.

Comment: Please read "[mcve]". We can't tell how you're writing the output. In general, using `read` to slurp the file isn't a good idea. In development we use tiny test files. In production you could run into files that exceed the available memory causing your code to break. Only if you can guarantee your input file is small should you use `read` like that. This might be an "[XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/153968)" where you're asking about Y but should ask about X. You're fixing a problem that might better be fixed by how you read the file.

Comment: I test your regex and it doesn't work for me.  I got empty string in the `ans` variable

Comment: Sorry about that! consider for filea.txt as `test` and `end`. Edited my question. @Aegis

Comment: Ok, but now your own code works just fine when writing `ans` to *fileb.txt*

Comment: I tried with example files. it is not working.. @Aegis filea.txt as `log
f
f
f
f 
timing_data
sd
ds
ds` and it is writing in new file as `["\nf\nf\nf\nf \n"]`. Seems the issue is with `scan(regex)`

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear and needs work, but you're using `read` in a way that can cause scalability problems.

Here's how to accomplish the same sort of task without using `read`:

```
content = []
DATA.each_line do |li|
  marker = li.lstrip
  if marker =~ /^in run/i .. marker =~ /^end of file/i
    content << li
  end
end
content # => ["in run\n", "]\n", "}\n", "end of file\n"]

__END__
test file
in run
]
}
end of file
```

The `..` (elipsis) is a multitool in Ruby (and other languages). We use it to define ranges but can also use it to flip-flop between logic states. In this case I'm using it in the second form, a "flip-flop".

When Ruby runs the code it checks

```
marker =~ /^in run/i`
```

If that is false the `if` fails and the code continues. If

```
marker =~ /^in run/i
```

succeeds, Ruby will remember that it succeeded and immediately test for

```
marker =~ /^end of file/i
```

If that fails Ruby will fall into the `if` block and do whatever is inside the block, then continue as normal.

The next loop of `each_line` will hit the `if` tests and `..` will remember that

```
marker =~ /^in run/i
```

succeeded previously and immediately test the second condition. If it is true it steps into the block and resets itself to a false again, so that any subsequent loops will fail until

```
marker =~ /^in run/i
```

returns true again.

This logic is really powerful and makes it easy to build code that can scan huge files, extracting portions of them.

There are other ways to do it but they generally run into messier logic.

In the example code I'm also using `__END__` which has some rarely seen magic to it also. You'll want to read about `__END__` and `DATA` if you don't understand what's happening.

If you're dealing with files in the GB or TB range, with lots of content you're grabbing, it might be smart to not accumulate too much into your data-gathering array `content`. A minor tweak will keep that from happening:

```
if marker =~ /^in run/i .. marker =~ /^end of file/i
  content << li
  next
end
unless content.empty?
  # do something that clears content:
end
```

In this code I'm using `DATA.each_line`. In real life you'd want to use `File.foreach` instead.

Comment: I'm not sure, but here in my case read is not the problem. Why i'm saying like this is, if i try to write the entire content read from filea.txt and write to fileb.txt it is having correct format as in filea.txt. No issues with that. The is due to the `scan(regex)` is there any other way to get the selected content without scan. Please note that i have a file with 'n' number of content to be selected (test --- end with be in 'n' number).

Comment: Your problem isn't `read` yet. I'm trying to head off that problem for you. Your question needs to be clarified in the question itself, not in a comment.